# Upgrading interface builder document?

Tags: xcode, interface, upgrade, ios7

After opening an old iOS 6 App Xcode asked me if I wanted to upgrade my IB doc to version 5.0 or skip. I hit skip so I could learn about what it would do first.

Now I'm unable to find a way to re-upgrade the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little looking around it's located in the file inspector under Interface Builder Document.

You simply change the "Opens in - Xcode 4.6" to "Default (5.0)" and it upgrades your IB doc